# Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a problem with useRef in TypeScript.
I want to type it but I get an error, like this:
[image]
My Container component is:

```
    const HeaderContainer: React.FC = () => {
    const addressElement = useRef<HTMLInputElement | undefined>();
    
        const handleCopy = useCallback(() => {
            if (addressElement.current !== undefined) {
                addressElement.current.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
            }
        }, [addressElement]);
    return <HeaderUI
        addressElement={addressElement}
        handleCopy={handleCopy} />
}
```

And UI component is:

```
interface IProps {
    handleCopy: (event: React.MouseEvent) => void,
    addressElement: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>,
}
const HeaderUI: React.FC<IProps> = ({
                                        handleCopy, addressElement
                                    }) => {
return <div className={classes.Header}>
        <div className={classes["Header-Section"]}>
            <span className={classes["Section-Title"]}>Персональный адрес кошелька:</span>
            {address && <input
              type="text"
              className={classes["Section-Value"]}
              ref={addressElement}
              value={address}
              readOnly/>}
        </div>
        <CopyLinkButtonContainer onClick={handleCopy}/>
    </div>;
}
```

Can you help please to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the type setting for addressElement should be null instead of undefined.

And, a better design to naming and passing ref is... just use ref.

```
<HeaderUI
        ref={addressElement}
        handleCopy={handleCopy} />
```

Then...

```
const HeaderUI: React.FC<IProps> = ({
                                        handleCopy, addressElement, ref
                                    }) => {
return <div className={classes.Header}>
        <div className={classes["Header-Section"]}>
            <span className={classes["Section-Title"]}>Персональный адрес кошелька:</span>
            {address && <input
              type="text"
              className={classes["Section-Value"]}
              ref={ref}
              value={address}
              readOnly/>}
        </div>
        <CopyLinkButtonContainer onClick={handleCopy}/>
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just pass null inside brackets like this.

```
const addressElement = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

Comment: more explanation would be nice, but _this_ should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 10):

The last line of the error is your solution: Your `useRef` expects the type

`HTMLInputElement | null`

but you're setting the type

`HTMLInputElement | undefined`

---

Just change your types to `null` instead of `undefined`:

```ts
const addressElement = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>();

{... addressElement: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>, ...}
```

and change your check to:

`if (addressElement.current !== null) {`

Answer (score 5):

basically it is saying that ref object is undefined so intialize this with null.

```
const ref= useRef(null);
```